# oauth for desktop and mobile with the same code

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, cordova, cross-domain

I'm using phonegap and I want to set up google oauth for mobile and web (e.g. desktop chrome) with the same code. The end result should be an app engine cookie on the client side (whether it is the inapp browser or a desktop browser).

Since I don't want my users to do the consent screen more than once, I need a refresh_token and not just an access_token. (also I've noticed that the cordova webview doesn't have access to cookies like the regular browser)

As I understand, a refresh_token can only be received if you're doing the protocol recommended for web servers, meaning first obtaining the code, then using it to obtain the access_token and refresh_token.

When I'm authenticating in this way, the protocol requires that I send the received code to google to receive the access token, but this is a cross domain request and is blocked on desktop browsers.

How can this be conveniently solved? What is the correct way to achieve the end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I crudely solved my problem using my server as a mediator for the cross-domain post requests.

So the flow works like this: I get an authentication code using a pop up window. Then the user enters the code and my javascript sends it to my server. Then the server sends a request for access_token and refresh_token to google, and sends it back to the user.

Seems to work well for now, and not very complicated.